# Usage of "not" in a while loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I'm a beginner and I've been going through [Learn to Program](https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_08.html) and I'm at Chapter 8 already.

Just want an explanation on the usage of 'not' in the while argument. To my understanding, while (not goodAnswer) means it is true, so if the answer is 'yes' or 'no' then goodAnswer will be true and the while loop should keep on going. But that is not the case as the program would end already. I might be missing something here on how 'not' really works. Can someone please help me understand this? Thanks!

```
goodAnswer = false
while (not goodAnswer)
  puts 'Do you like eating tacos?'
  answer = gets.chomp.downcase
  if (answer == 'yes' or answer == 'no')
    goodAnswer = true
  else
    puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no".'
  end
end
```

Comment: It loops until you enter a valid answer. That's all this snippet does.

Comment: You could also write `while !goodAnswer` (or--using snake_case--`while !good_answer`), which removes the need for the [parens](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#bang-not-not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**While loop**

I've re-written the code slightly on the *second line* to make it more explicit. It does exactly the same thing.

```
goodAnswer = false
while (not goodAnswer) == true
  puts 'Do you like eating tacos?'
  answer = gets.chomp.downcase
  if (answer == 'yes' or answer == 'no')
    goodAnswer = true
  else
    puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no".'
  end
end
```

Think of `(not goodAnswer)` as a single entity. `goodAnswer = false`, so    `(not goodAnswer) = true`. Thus the following condition is satisfied:

```
while (not goodAnswer) == true #condition satisfied, so the loop runs.
```

***if* statement:**

```
 if (answer == 'yes' or answer == 'no')
    goodAnswer = true
```

As soon as `goodAnswer` equals *true*, `(not goodAnswer)` naturally equals *false*. So now the condition:

```
while (not goodAnswer) == true
```

fails and the *while loop* ceases.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is 'yes' or 'no', then goodAnswer is true.  However the condition of the while loop is "not goodAnswer", which mean the opposite of what you state.  It will be false (not goodAnswer == not true == false).  Then it will stop looping because it received a valid input ('yes' or 'no').

So essentially, "not " means, the opposite of , much like in english, you would say, "If I don't have a good answer yet..".

Comment: Hi, my interpretation of it is that the statement "while (not goodAnswer)" would always be the opposite of "goodAnswer" and thus, will keep looping forever. I think that's my question -on what the logic of using "not" is. But based from your explanation, now that the value of "while (not goodAnswer)" has changed, it will stop looping. Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: It will stop looping when goodAnswer is true.  I feel you are overthinking it here.

Comment: yeah I was overthinking as I was taking it too literally. Was just not sure if my understanding or how i would use 'not' is correct. amazing how logic is subtly hidden in everyday english. anyway thanks!